# Ruby on rails using whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cron, whenever

I need to use whenever in my app 
How can I for example send an email to my Course.teacher on certain days between Course.start_at and Course.end_at . I dont understand the use of whenever gem and it seems there is no good tutorials using this in models and using their methods .

Answer (score 1):

The [whenever Gem documentation](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is pretty clear on how to use the Gem in rails, but it may be unclear to you how to configure cron jobs ('whenever' is simply a front end for cron).

As an alternative to cron, I would suggest using Heroku Scheduler (and deploying to Heroku instead of hosting it locally/on a Linux instance with cron installed).  Heroku doesn't have cron, but they do support free servers and a free tool (Scheduler) that lets you trigger Rake tasks at specific times recurring each day.

[Getting Started with Rails 4.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) and then configure the Heroku Scheduler AddOn.

The general procedure for your problem is:

1. Set up a (Rails) server
2. Set up a scheduler
3. Set up mail sending
4. Set up task(s) to trigger from scheduler that send mail